# Print a name on a diploma in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a pile of already printed diplomas with blank spaces for the name. I'd like to print a name on each diploma in the right place. The person who's going to be printing it is inexperienced so to avid troubles I want to put the diploma's image in the background. So that this person sees where he types.

I put an image in the background by Format > Background but it doesn't fit the page and I can't find the way to stretch it. Can this be done?

If not, than whats the word's page resolution?

Maybe there's a better approach?

Comment: Use hit and trial to find the correct location, place a textbox there, remove textbox borders and if necessary use mailmerge

Comment: Also note that most printers are not perfect in alignment so it wont be as good as it could have been

Comment: To expand on Akash, it even changes per print driver per printer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just insert an image, right-click > layout > behind text.

Set your margins to equal the size of the page.

Then scale the image to the size you want.

Next, insert a textbox at the place you want the text.

Remove image before printing if you don't want to print it.

Answer (score 0):

Word's default page layout is set to a vertical A4 (21 cm X 29.7 cm).

It is impossible to use a A4 sized image as a background as Word will caution you that the file is too big. Instead, create a custom picture watermark and make sure the scale is set at 100%.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Microsoft Publisher, this would be more Ideal if you trying to fit an a backgroud image to full viewing are of the page.

But something you can do on Both Publisher and Word is insert a **text box**, and then set the **Text Wrapping property** to "**In Front of Text**" so that you can position the text box anywhere in the document you wish.  This will take some setting up on your part making sure the **font, font size, position, and page orientation are all correct** (basically print and compare).  Once you have where you want it, just save the document as template so it won't accidently be changed and saved.  Then all you have to is make sure that who ever does the printing places the diploma templates in the right orientation (typically facing down).

Word 2007/2010

1. Insert -> Text Box

   [image: Text Box]
2. Format -> Text Wrapping

[image: Text Wrapping]

Comment: Word also has text boxes.

Comment: Did you read my post?